# What format do sites like Facebook use to store data for personal profiles?

Tags: xml, database, facebook, storage, bigdata

I recently started dealing with large sets of data stored in XML files.  I've always wondered how Facebook and other networking sites store all the information associated with individual profiles (name, profile picture, wall posts, etc.) and I feel like XML is definitely not the best way to store so much information. I've tried finding information about it with google but haven't been having too much luck.

How do huge sites such as Facebook store and deal with so much data?  I would really like to do some reading about this, so if you know of any good websites please let me know!

Answer (score 12):

Rather than being stored in an XML file, Facebook uses a relational database--specifically, a modified version of MySQL.  If you're interested in their implementation, the MySQL official site has a whole page of articles related to Facebook's MySQL usage at http://www.mysql.com/customers/view/?id=757

Comment: Well this is somewhat misleading: ""We generally don't use it (MySQL) for Joins and we aren't running complex queries that are pulling multiple tables together inside of a database," David Recordon (Facebook). They do not use it as a rational database. MySQL wants that everyone believe they do. You can find to quote via the link you posted.

Comment: @dmeister no one really high-load service uses joins... only direct selects & then they make joins and other data manipulations at application server.

Answer (score 0):

Well for storing data under facebook ,they use a new database that is known as "NoSQL" means accessing of data fm DB without having SQL.To know more about it just search for NOSQL in the google. M sure u will definately get ur ans.

Comment: NoSQL means 'not only sql'